# App working fine in facebook canvas but for loggin using Django auth

Tags: django, facebook, https, django-authentication, facebook-canvas

I have an app that I want to be in facebook canvas, but when trying to loggin, I keep getting `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://****.herokuapp.com/login"`

I use Django in the backend, so I'm using [Django Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

The code of the button for going to the loggin page is:

```
<a href="/login"><div class="btn btn-register"><h2><font color="white">LOGGIN</font></h2></div></a>
```

And the error I get in Firefox is:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://****.herokuapp.com/login"
```

In Firefox I also get:

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) iframe
```

And in Chrome:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://apps.facebook.com/****/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://****.herokuapp.com/register/?next=/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Any ideas?

**PD:**

If I register in `****`.herokuapp.com an then I enter in apps.facebook.com`/****` it goes in automaticaly and everything works fine